# Schematic diagram of comparison between mathematical structures

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I am looking for diagrams which relate/compare various fields in mathematics or mathematical structures/spaces. My objective is to find out which area of mathematics I should study in order to answer a research question. In other words, I am looking for a hierarchy of mathematical structures and how they are related.s

I found a few such diagrams but looking for more definitive ones. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am not sure it's a good idea to mix two different questions (relations between fields vs. relations between concepts in _one_ field). Wouldn't it be better to consider asking them separately? By the way, since your question (as it stands) asks for quite general relations, would diagrams at http://www.johndcook.com/modes_of_convergence.html also satisfy you?

Comment: Thanks. I am talking about diagram like this: http://frank-oertel-math.de/Math_Genealogy.jpg I am looking for diagrams in statistics, probability, stochastic process, machine learning etc.